# Spring Cloud Gateway log 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to log incoming requests. So I've added this class to log incoming requests:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class LoggingFilter implements GlobalFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        Set<URI> uris = exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(GATEWAY_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_URL_ATTR, Collections.emptySet());
        String originalUri = (uris.isEmpty()) ? "Unknown" : uris.iterator().next().toString();
        Route route = exchange.getAttribute(GATEWAY_ROUTE_ATTR);
        URI routeUri = exchange.getAttribute(GATEWAY_REQUEST_URL_ATTR);
        log.info("Incoming request " + originalUri + " is routed to id: " + route.getId()
            + ", uri:" + routeUri);
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }
}
```

It works perfect with successful request. But when route not found there is no message in log.
Any ideas how I can do that? Thanks!

Comment: I think Filters only apply request that matches a configured route - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/#gateway-combined-global-filter-and-gatewayfilter-ordering

Comment: @Dhananjay ,yes. But also I want to log failed routing attempts and I have no idea how to do it